# How to define a View as Drop Zone in React Native Drag and Drop component?

Tags: react-native

Hi :) I'm wondering how to define a certain View as a dropzone or how to create on hover reaction of View while dragging over.

The only solution that I found was to define the dropzone as a static area with respect to global coordinates of the screen. The Problem is that in my case I need to drop the element on one of the many dropzones Views inside a ScrollableView.

It would be also nice to fire an event on a Dropzone View during PanResponder Drag Gesture over this View. Thanks!